# Glass XE 18.3 tap to accept not working when using ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, image, google-glass

I'm using this code to take a picture:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE_REQUEST);
```

After the picture is taken, I need to tap to accept the picture and `onActivityResult` can be called before. It was working well.

However, after updating to XE 18.3, after I take a picture, when I tap, the picture never disappears and `onActivityResult` doesn't get called. The only way is to swipe down to cancel.

Has anyone met this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encountered this issue as well. To help raise visibility with Google I posted about it in the official Explorer community and linked to this StackOverflow post. They responded and confirmed that we've stumbled upon a bug in XE18.3. A fix is in the works but it may take a couple of weeks.

Just in case you don't have an Explorer Community account, you can find a screen grab of my conversation [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0OeyX.png).

I'll post again on this question should Google provide any additional information.

Comment: Google has confirmed that this issue was identified too late to be included in the upcoming XE19.1 release. Hopefully it will be included in a minor 19.2 release shortly thereafter. I'll post more when I learn more.

Comment: Well thanks, seems I also need to develop my own APK.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue.

Try this link . I am working on it right now as well

https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=308